# OPEN MP with For loop and pointer operation

Tags: c++, pointers, parallel-processing, openmp, directshow

### Context

I am doing a directshow filter that changes the contrast and the brightness of every frames. The pointer to the first pixel of the first frame is : `RGBTRIPLE *prgb = (RGBTRIPLE*) pData;`

Also, `int numPixels  = cxImage * cyImage;` is the number of pixels per frame.

### The loop

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int iPixel=0; iPixel < numPixels; iPixel++ ) {

    prgb->rgbtGreen = prgb->rgbtGreen * _contrastPower + _brightnessPower;
    prgb->rgbtBlue  = prgb->rgbtBlue  * _contrastPower + _brightnessPower;
    prgb->rgbtRed   = prgb->rgbtRed   * _contrastPower + _brightnessPower;  

    if(prgb->rgbtGreen>255) prgb->rgbtGreen = 255;
    if(prgb->rgbtBlue>255)  prgb->rgbtBlue  = 255;
    if(prgb->rgbtRed>255)   prgb->rgbtRed   = 255;


    prgb++;
}
```

### Problem

The output stream is uglyfied. Let's say we have to threads using the same pointer we increment, of course they are going to end up racing and causing weird problems.

Also, I tryed removing the int iPixel and using only the prgb*, but couldn't get the syntax down.

### Question

Is it possible to make a parallel for loop while using pointer operations ? If so, how ?

Comment: Pixel processing is way too small task for parallelization. I would say the key factor in performance is SIMD processing (using assembly, intrinsics or third party primitive function). Then if the image if large, you might want to split segments of the image (several full lines, or at the very least one line of pixels per atomic task).

Comment: Since this is memory bandwidth band you're best option is to increase the efficiency of the memory bandwidth. If your image is larger (`1920x1024*4=7.5MB`) than half your L3 cache then you should consider using non-temporal stores (e.g. with `_mm_stream_ps()`).. Multiple threads will increase the bandwidth as well but at most on order a factor of two.

Comment: @RomanR. I also plan on going with SIMD processing in a couples days. I wanted to test the parallelization time results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `prgb` is a shared pointer and incrementing it in each thread without any data protection leads to data races. Instead, your code should look like similar to this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
for (int iPixel=0; iPixel < numPixels; iPixel++ ) {
   RGBTRIPLE *ppixel = prgb + iPixel;

   ppixel->rgbtGreen = ppixel->rgbtGreen * _contrastPower + _brightnessPower;
   ppixel->rgbtBlue  = ppixel->rgbtBlue  * _contrastPower + _brightnessPower;
   ppixel->rgbtRed   = ppixel->rgbtRed   * _contrastPower + _brightnessPower;  

   if(ppixel->rgbtGreen>255) ppixel->rgbtGreen = 255;
   if(ppixel->rgbtBlue>255)  ppixel->rgbtBlue  = 255;
   if(ppixel->rgbtRed>255)   ppixel->rgbtRed   = 255;
}
```

The algorithm is memory bound on modern CPUs, therefore do not expect performance to be linearly proportional to the number of threads if the image data does not fit entirely in the CPU cache.

Comment: Your code works perfectly. And now we can appreciate the HUGE DROP in performance. HAHA ! it's about 3 to 8 times slower ! Very interesting. Thanks Hristo.

Comment: @Dave, that's strange. One is to expect some overhead from OpenMP in your case, but a drop in performance is way too much. How big are the images and how are you measuring the performance? Hopefully you are not victim of the classical using-`clock()`-in-threaded-programs-on-Unix.

Comment: @HristoIliev Well, the video is 300x300. The code is C++ executed on windows OS. I'm using a popular way ( I think ) to mesure the performances something in time or ctime library. It looks like I have good performances, and then, a frame takes VERY long to be processed , like 14 MS while the others takes about 0.4 MS. So the average ends up being much higher than before.